# What's the movement to break free from ties?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs, phrase-requests

With all their limbs **tied** down to a bed, what do we call the panicked **movement** of someone trying **to break free** somehow?

> He tried to ____________ out of the bed.

Comment: One *struggles* against his restraints.

Comment: Yep, *struggle* is the first term that came to mind.  "Struggle to break free" is quite idiomatic, used both literally and figuratively.

Comment: @HotLicks You may recall that I asked you if there was anything you don't know. Only afterwards did I grasp your answer. I'm slow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I agree that *struggling* should suffice in general, in the specific case of trying to break free from restraints (like ropes), ***wriggling*** works better.

> He tried to ***wriggle*** out of the bed.

ODO:

> **[wriggle](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/wriggle)**
>   *VERB*
>
> **1** Twist and turn with quick writhing movements.
>   [no object] ‘she kicked and **wriggled** but he held her firmly’
>   [with object] ‘she
>   **wriggled** her bare, brown toes’
>
> **1.1** [no object, with adverbial of direction] Move in a particular direction with wriggling movements.
>   ‘Susie **wriggled** out of her
>   clothes’
>
> ‘With a brief, feeble attempt she tried to **wriggle** out of what bound
>   her wrists, but to no avail.’

M-W:

> **[wriggle](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wriggle)**;
>   wriggled, wriggling
>   *intransitive verb*
>
> 1 :  to move the body or a bodily part to and fro with short writhing
>   motions like a worm :  squirm
>   2 :  to move or advance by twisting
>   and turning
>   3 :  to **extricate** or insinuate oneself or reach a
>   goal as if by wriggling
>
> She managed to **wriggle** free of her ropes.
>
> **[extricate](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/extricate)**
>   *transitive verb*
>
> **2** :  to free or remove from an entanglement or difficulty

Answer (score 2):

You *strain* against your shackles.

[Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.com/browse/strain):

> 12.
>   to pull forcibly:
>   a dog straining at a leash.
>
> 13.
>   to stretch one's muscles, nerves, etc., to the utmost.
>
> 14.
>   to make violent physical efforts; strive hard.
>
> 15.
>   to resist forcefully; balk:
>   to strain at accepting an unpleasant fact.

Comment: @habibhassani - note that *wriggle* and *extricate* suggest success, where *strain* implies failure.  That is not absolute -- but it could help you distinguish among the options offered.

Answer (score 1):

How about *wrestle*?

> He tried to wrestle out of the bed.

From Oxford Dictionaries:

> [*wrestle*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/wrestle): move
>   or manipulate (something) with difficulty.

Answer (score 1):

You might try *flail.*

> [flail](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/flail): Wave or swing wildly.

Answer (score 1):

Burst could work.

Dictionary.com:

> verb (used without object), burst or, often bursted, bursting.
>
> 2. to issue forth suddenly and forcibly, as from confinement or through an obstacle:

He tried to *burst* out of the bed.